# JSP program always returning null value

Tags: java, xml, jsp, null

I'm encountering some problem with my jsp code. Here is the code [Get_Values.java]:

```
public class Get_values {

 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String msisdn = request.getParameter("msisdn");
    temp = new Test().parseXml();
    out.println("<b><font color='blue'>MSISDN :</font></b>" + "<b>" + temp[0] + "</b>" + "<br>"); 
 }
}
```

And here is the code for Test.java

```
public class Test {
 public String [] temp= new String [50];
public String [] parseXml() {
    SAXParser sp = factory.newSAXParser();
    sp.parse("test.xml", handler);
DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("location")) {
                nodeName = attributes.getValue(qName);
            }
        }

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
                temp[0] = value;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                temp[1] = value;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("z")) {
                temp[2] = value;
            }
        }

        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            value = new String(ch, start, length);
        }
    };
return temp;
}
}
```

But the value of temp is always returning as null when I exectue the "Get_values.war" file. But when I execute the java program, its working fine. I think the "test.xml" is not being read properly when i execute the war file. What may be the reason? Should  I explicitly include the file in my jsp program??

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: i don't see `temp` declared anywhere in your `Test` class

Comment: @abu Sorry for omitting the temp. Copying problems.

Comment: @home I tried using a debugger, and i the program encountered a breakpoint at this  "sp.parse("test.xml", handler);" line. I have no idea what to do. Is it because the test.xml is not being read?

Comment: @user1640534 : May be because path for test.xml is wrong. Try to put your test.xml in root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally it worked. It was because of the path problem. I had to give the full path.

```
C:\\xampp\\tomcat\\webapps\\Location_API\\WEB-INF\\classes\\location\\test.xml
```

It worked like charm. Thanks all for your valuable time. :)

Comment: You could use `/` instead of \\. Forward-slash `/` is OS-independent.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad thanks for the tip. I thought the '/' was OS dependent.